# Dropdown Menu Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have categories seeded to my database within a 'category' model, what I'm trying to do is have a dropdown on the new post page which allows me to select what category it belongs to.

The problem is I'm currently getting below:

[image]

This is the field I'm currently using within the form.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.select :category, Category.all, :prompt => "Select One" %>
  </div>
```

Any help would be fantastic.

Thanks

UPDATE

Offers Controller Create

```
  def create
    @offer = Offer.new(offer_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @offer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @offer, notice: 'Offer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @offer }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @offer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, :prompt => "Select One" %>
```

More info can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html).

Don't forget to add `:category_id` to permitted parameters list for `Post` in your controller.

Comment: Getting 'undefined method `category_id' for #<Offer:0x000000065105f8>' with that one

Comment: @Jonathan do you have `category_id` field in `offers` table?

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't migrated! Thanks answer accepted!

Comment: I seem to be getting an AssociatedTypeMismatch (Category(#22695080) expected, got String(#17247020)

Comment: @Jonathan you should use `category_id` field in `offer_params` too. You are not probably using `category`.

Comment: It's in the offer params :(

Comment: can you show me `offers_controller`'s method `create`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89737/discussion-between-dimakura-and-jonathan).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing `Category.all` - which gives you back an ActiveRecord Object you have to specify the attribute on the Object you want.

There is a built in form helper for that:

`<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>`

Rails guides for form helpers might help: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html